# iPhone, anything cool I can do to provide two options when someone taps my info button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

At the moment I have a help file view which is displayed but I'd also like to show a tutorial.

I want to give the user some to tap on to choose.

Something cool, any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'cool'? Would it be cool to single-tap to get info and double-tap to launch tutorial?

Comment: Please don't do anything "cool."

Comment: The simplest (albeit not exactly *cool*) would be to show a UIActionSheet with two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own popover style translucent view with two buttons in it...